# Phpcloud and Mysql Workbench connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have been struggling how to connect Mysql Workbench with Phpcloud.com Mysql instance since friday ? Below there is error which I get [image](http://zapodaj.net/70b091f9145b8.png.html)

Anyone has did it working properly ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message about the initial package usually indicates there was no server found at that address and port. Keep in mind that due to the SSH tunnel the remote server appears like it is a local one. The remote end of the tunnel sees the server locally too, since it is on the same machine as the MySQL server (I assume). So what you need is the localhost address for the MySQL server. The other thing to check are the ports: 1) Does the SSH connection really work with port 22? 2) Is your firewall blocking this port? 3) Is the remote MySQL server really listening on port 3306?

As a side node: on Windows you can usually just press Ctrl+C in error messages to copy the message to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the second section "Managing your Database Instance" at http://www.phpcloud.com/help/accessing-the-db

You need to establish a tunnel using SSH client (putty will be best in your case) and then access the server on port 13306 (local).

I don't use Workbench but I assume it tries to establish a regular SSH connection and not a tunnel and this will not work.